# Semantic search system in Java

Tags: java, python, nlp, semantics

I want to implement a semantic search system in Java. Sesame will be embedded into my system to store and manipulate rdf data directly, and I want to use Tomcat, JSP and Servlet. But I also need to do natural language processing, which I know Python is really good at. So it there any way that I can merge Python code in my Java web codes? Or is there any good tools dealing with NLP in java? 
I think I'm a little confused since I know little about NLP area.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apace Lucene is the best http://lucene.apache.org/core/ - also read about it extension like a [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: I did implement a project in Solr, so I think it's not comptible for dealing with rdf data, maybe it's not a good choice. Thanks for your advice, but I should use Sesame instead of Solr something.

Comment: Do you think OpenNLP will do me a favor?

Answer (score 0):

NLP can be done with java too..here is the link

http://opennlp.apache.org/

And also if you want to go for python for NLP then you can use [NLTK](http://nltk.org/)